# Sorting 2D string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am using Arrays.Sort() function in java to sort a names in 2D array storing names and corresponding numbers. I want number to remain in the same indices as to the corresponding names. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

CODE

```
String[][] contact = new String[3][3];
contact[0][0] = "b";
contact[0][1] = "c";
contact[0][2] = "a";
contact[1][0] = "2";
contact[1][1] = "3";
contact[1][2] = "1";
Arrays.sort(contact[0]);
```

Example:

b c a

2 3 1

OUTPUT:

a b c

2 3 1

I want to get:

a b c

1 2 3

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried? We need more information. How are you storing your arrays?

Comment: You are going to have to provide some code showing what your data structure looks like. It sounds like you want to sort one array and have a different array "follow along" based on the original positions in both arrays... but I could be wrong.

Comment: You are right @JimGarrison...That's exactly what I want, how do I do it??

Comment: You probably can't user Arrays.sort for this data structure. Passing in contact[0] would mean it knows nothing about contact[1]. Would you consider making it a 1D array?

Comment: Yes, I am open to other solutions and how will that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you sort your array make a copy of it, then after sorting loop through the sorted one and use `originalArray.indexOf(newArray[i])` to get the original index of the string, then set  the new "index array"[i] to the value of the original index array[original index of the string].

You need to turn the original array into a list before you do this with `Arrays.asList(originalArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MatrixCell{

 private Integer x = 0;
 private Integer y = 0;
 private String name = "";

 public MatrixCell(int x, int y, String name){
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.name = name;
 }

 //getters and setters
}
```

Then make an array of MatrixCell and done. Although this way you have to make too the sort algorithm.

Comment: No you're assuming that I'm assuming

Comment: I kind of agree with Eric here. If OP were to implement your answer they would have to rewrite a majority of their program versus implementing one of the million brute-force algorithms that can be used to sort a 2-D array.

Comment: @Tdorno I wrote the answer before the additional info provided by the OP.